# How to Bind LINQ result variable into Gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview, asp.net-membership

I have written a simple LINQ which is retrieving username with roles from membership .Now as per my need i have to bind and display it into gridview but its not happening ...here is my code...

This is my gridview code...

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```

And here is my server side code with LINQ query..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGridviewData();      

}



protected void BindGridviewData()
{
    var roles = from MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers()
                select new
                {
                    user = u,
                    roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName)
                };

    GridView1.DataSource = roles;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

But its not happening  ....Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Thank sir for ur response sir i am very new to LINq ..Plz give me the syantax ..Thank you./.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **FirstOrDefault()** method.

try this:

```
var roles = from MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers()
                select new { User = u.UserName, 
                    Role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName).FirstOrDefault() 
               };
```

Answer (score 3):

Here example shows binding (employee details) with the condition employee age >=20

[Check out this link to get more ideas](http://www.thedevelopertips.com/DotNet/LINQ/Binding-Gridview-with-LINQ.aspx?Id=94)

This works fine

```
            var result = from c in objDataContext.Employees
                         where c.EmployeeAge >= 20
                         select c;                
            List<Employee> lstEmployee = result.ToList();
            gridviewEmp.DataSource = lstEmployee;
            gridviewEmp.DataBind();
```

[Getting started with LINQ to SQL](http://www.thedevelopertips.com/DotNet/LINQ/Getting-started-with-LINQ.aspx?Id=93)

Answer (score 2):

Datasource for gridview should be enumerable.

Try

```
  GridView1.DataSource = roles.ToList();
  GridView1.DataBind();
```

Do not forget to add referance to **System.Linq**

Please mark as answer if you find this useful